How to compress image in flutter web. Facing problem with uint8list
This is my code which I am using:
void onSubmit() async {
  Uint8List compressedFile = [] as Uint8List;
  if (file != null) {
    final selectedFile = file!.files.first;

    final isPDF = selectedFile.name.split(".").last == "pdf";
    if (isPDF) {
      logger.w("Is PDF is executing...");
      if (selectedFile.size > 2 * 1024 * 1024) {
        logger.w("PDF is greater than 2 MB");
        snackBar(context, "Pdf is above 2 MB. Max upload size is 2 MB.");
        return;
      }
    } else {
      compressedFile = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
        selectedFile.bytes!,
        quality: 50,
      );
      logger.w("Image is executing...");

      logger.w("Is 2 MB: ${is2mbFile(compressedFile)}");
      if (!is2mbFile(compressedFile)) return;
    }
    logger.w("This is running....");
    await updateSellerImages(
            widget.sellerId,
            MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                isPDF ? selectedFile.bytes as Uint8List : compressedFile,
                filename: selectedFile.name,
                contentType: MediaType(isPDF ? "application" : "image",
                    selectedFile.name.split(".").last)),
            widget.imageType)
        .then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        navigationPop(context);
        widget.onRefresh();
      } else {
        snackBar(
            context, "There is issue with upload, please try again later!");
      }
    });
  }
}

Here the file is PlatformFile which comes from FilePicker .
The error I get:
Expected a value of type 'Uint8List', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

How can I fix this error?
Edit:
 compressedFile = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
      selectedFile.bytes!,
      quality: 50,
    );

this is the function which is causing the issue .
I got this error because of the function from where my code breaks
DartError: Expected a value of type 'Function', but got one of type 'Null'
is there any platform specific things which I am missing????

If what you have is a List<int>, convert it with https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.fromList.html

[] as Uint8List is not valid for multiple reasons.  Doing List<T> list = [] as List<T>; is wrong because it prevents the type of [] from being inferred.  The [] literal with an unspecified element type will be treated as List<dynamic> before being cast as List<int> (which also is the wrong way to cast containers).  Furthermore, Uint8List compressedFile  = []; would also be wrong because you can't initialize a Uint8List from a List literal; you must Uint8List.fromList.

selectedFile.bytes as Uint8List is possibly wrong (but I can't tell without knowing what selectedFile.bytes is).  If the runtime type of selectedFile.bytes is List<dynamic>, then that is the wrong way to cast a List.  If you control selectedFile.file, then you should fix it to use Uint8List instead of List<dynamic>.  If you don't control it, you again will need to use Uint8List.fromList.

@jamesdlin brother I have tred using the Uint8List but still I get error as Expected a value of type 'Function', but got one of type 'Null' . and that is coming from FlutterImageCompress.compressFromList function . I am not sure what is going on ! can you help
